# GitLab CI/CD variable value doesn't pass to pipeline job script

Tags: docker, .net-core, gitlab, cicd

#### Summary

One of my defined CI/CD variables value doesn't pass to pipeline job script, though others pass correct.
The variable name I'm talking about is `APPSETTINGS`, see its usage at `pre-deploy_job`.

I'm trying to pass its value as a build argument for docker there. Other variables are `HOST`, `USER`, `ID_RSA` and they work fine.
What have I missed?

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
default:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - pre-deploy
  - deploy

variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH: '*/*/'
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json'
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*'
    - '$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
  policy: pull-push

before_script:
  - 'dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
  - 'echo $APPSETTINGS'


build_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - branches
  script:
    - 'dotnet build --no-restore'


test_job:
  stage: test
  only:
    - branches
  script:
    - 'dotnet test ./Tests --no-restore --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=..\artifacts\{assembly}-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"'
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths: 
     - ./**/*test-result.xml
    reports:
      junit: 
       - ./**/*test-result.xml


pre-deploy_job:
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: pre-deploy
  only:
    - master
    - dev
  before_script:
    - docker login ${CI_REGISTRY} -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
  script:
    - docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest --build-arg APPSETTINGS=${APPSETTINGS} --no-cache .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest
  after_script:
    - docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}


deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
    - dev
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apt-get update 
    - apt-get install -y openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST "docker login ${CI_REGISTRY} -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST "docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST "docker container rm -f tech-connect || true"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST "docker run -d -p 80:80 --name tech-connect ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: $HOST
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG APPSETTINGS
RUN [ "sh", "-c", "echo $APPSETTINGS" ]
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TC/TC.csproj", "TC/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TC/TC.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TC"
RUN dotnet build "TC.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN cp -f $APPSETTINGS /app/build/appsettings.json

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TC.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TC.dll"]
```

#### What is the current behavior?

[image]

[image]

In plain text:

```
47 #6 [build 2/9] RUN echo ""
48 #6 0.777
```

```
#11 [build 9/9] RUN cp -f /app/build/appsettings.json
#11 0.526 cp: missing destination file operand after "/app/build/appsettings.json
#11 0.526 Try 'cp --help' for more information.
#11 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c cp -f $APPSETTINGS /app/build/appsettings.json" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
-----
 > [build 9/9] RUN cp -f /app/build/appsettings.json:
-----
process "/bin/sh -c cp -f $APPSETTINGS /app/build/appsettings.json" did,not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

As you can see, the value of `$APPSETTINGS` is empty inside the Dockerfile.

#### What is the expected behavior?

Value of `$APPSETTINGS`should contain non-empty value, same as defined in GitLab CI/CD variables.

#### Relevant logs and/or screenshots

[image]

In GitLab:

Update variable:

- Key: "`APPSETTINGS`",
- Value: "test",
- Type: "variable",
- environment scope: "staging",
- Flags: "Protect variable".

Comment: Maybe something related to `Environment scope` to be set to `staging`

Comment: @OlegI I'm sure not. Other variables defined in the same scope

Comment: Are the other variables also protected?

Comment: @Schmango, yeah

Comment: can you try with just `--build-arg APPSETTINGS="$APPSETTINGS"` ? According to docker docs, it should also pick up APPSETTINGS variable when specifed as   `--build-arg APPSETTINGS`.   "You may also use the --build-arg flag without a value, in which case the value from the local environment will be propagated into the Docker container being built".  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-arg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mentioned that the [environment scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/) of the `APPSETTINGS` variable is set to "`staging`". This could be the reason why the variable is not available in your script.

The `APPSETTINGS` variable will only be injected into jobs that are run on the `staging` environment, and from your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, it appears that the `pre-deploy_job` does *not* specify an environment.

You could try removing the environment scope from the variable, or set the environment for the `pre-deploy_job` to `staging`.

> I'm sure not. Other variables defined in the same scope

True, but `APPSETTINGS` is used in `pre-deploy_job`, again without any environment definition.

---

Furthermore, your `APPSETTINGS` variable is also set as a **protected variable**, which means it will [only be provided to protected branches and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154236/6309).

If your `dev` branch is not protected, then the `APPSETTINGS` variable will not be available to jobs run on that branch.

You could verify if your branches are protected or try removing the protected flag.

See also "[GitLab Environment Variables are not Resolved in Your Pipeline — Here are Some Fixes.](https://medium.com/devops-with-valentine/gitlab-environment-variables-are-not-resolved-in-your-pipeline-here-are-some-fixes-e5b8494e452a)" from [Valentin Despa](https://vdespa.com/).

---

Note that you could try setting a default value for the `APPSETTINGS` variable in your Dockerfile to see if this resolves the issue, like so:

```
ARG APPSETTINGS=default_value
```

This would allow you to check if the issue is with the passing of the variable or with the Dockerfile itself.

Or, should you use `--build-arg APPSETTINGS="$APPSETTINGS"` during your `docker build` command, you would need to add `ARG APPSETTINGS` in your Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG APPSETTINGS
RUN [ "sh", "-c", "echo $APPSETTINGS" ]
...
```

This `ARG APPSETTINGS` line makes the `APPSETTINGS` variable available for use in the Dockerfile, and its value is the one that you provide in the `--build-arg` option during the `docker build` command. If no value is provided, `APPSETTINGS` will be undefined.

Please note that the scope of the `ARG` instruction is from the line it is declared on to the end of the current build stage. So if you need to use the `APPSETTINGS` variable in a different stage, you'd need to re-declare it in that stage.

---

To confirm all this, you could also try echoing the `APPSETTINGS` variable in the `pre-deploy_job` to see if the variable is available at that point, like so:

```yaml
pre-deploy_job:
  # ...
  script:
    - echo $APPSETTINGS
    - docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest --build-arg APPSETTINGS=${APPSETTINGS} --no-cache .
    # ...
```

This should help you figure out where exactly the variable is getting lost.

---

The [OP anatol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4269118/anatol) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76439707/gitlab-ci-cd-variable-value-doesnt-pass-to-pipeline-job-script/76465759#comment134890926_76465759):

> The issue was on a surface - `dev` branch is not in the `staging` env, I added it just to `test` and overlooked `env` behavior.

This kind of oversight happens quite often. In GitLab CI/CD, environment variables can be scoped to specific environments, and if the branch you are building is not part of the environment where the variable is scoped, it will not have access to that variable.

Since you have identified that the issue was due to the `dev` branch not being part of the `staging` environment, you can either:

- Change the Environment Scope of the Variable, that is of the `APPSETTINGS` variable so that it is available to the `dev` branch.
  For example, you could remove the environment scope, making the variable available to all environments.
- or, what you did: include the `dev` branch in the `staging` environment.
  You can do this by modifying the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and configuring the `environment` section in the `pre-deploy_job`:

  ```yaml
  pre-deploy_job:
  # ...
  environment:
      name: staging
      url: $HOST
      on_stop: stop_environment
  only:
      refs:
      - master
      - dev
  # ...
  ```

  Make sure that the `APPSETTINGS` variable is not set as "Protected" if you are using non-protected branches like `dev`.

Once you make these changes, the `APPSETTINGS` variable should be passed correctly to the job script.

Comment: Note to self: That was my **30000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 177 months), a bit more than 7 months after the [29000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74593456/6309). Before that: [28000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72697130/6309), [27000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504269/6309), [26000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68190336/6309), [25000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370954/6309), [24000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62688871/6309), [23000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853332/63099), ...

Comment: the issue was on a surface - `dev` branch is not in the `staging` env, I added it just to test and overlooked env behavior. thank you for helping me gather one's thoughts

Comment: @anatol Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.